# Change Visual Studio 2013 Summary Tag Color on Dark Theme

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2013, tags

When I have the Blue Theme on VS2013, the summary shows as:

[image: Summary on Blue Theme]

But when I change to my preferred theme, the Dark theme, the summary tag becomes all green:

[image: Summary on Dark Theme]

I like the grayed out version, since it gives more attention to the summary's text, instead of the tag itself, I just can't find how to change it on the Dark theme... any ideas? (I tried the [color theme editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe), but didn't help much).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015, the following will change the slashes, summary tag, and description:

XML Doc Comments - Delimiter

XML Doc Comments - Name

XML Doc Comments - Text

Comment: This also works in Visual Studio 2017 - just tested it

Answer (score 3):

have a look at:

Tools => Options => Environment => Fonts and Colors => Text Editor => XML Doc Tag

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Have you tested it? I am away from the pc to test it now, but I remember I tried something like it before

Answer (score 2):

The above answer didn't work for me with VS 2015.

But this did the trick: 
Tools => Options => Environment => Fonts and Colors => Text Editor => **XML Doc Comment - Name**  
Change the foreground color.
*Note:* This changes the color of 'summary' tag only.
You can play around with other XML Doc Comment items to suit you preferences.