# Editing XML Summary Tag on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Does anyone know how to change the font color of a summary tag in VS-2022, like the below?

```
/// <summary>
///  Returns a number
/// </summary>
/// <param name="num"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

Thank You!

Comment: Seems it's the same as in previous VS.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070902/change-visual-studio-2013-summary-tag-color-on-dark-theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to Visual Studio 2022.
- Click on "Tools" in the top menu.
- Select "Options" from the dropdown menu.
- In the "Options" dialog box, expand   the "Environment" section and select "Fonts and Colors."
- In the "Show settings for" dropdown, select "Text Editor."
- In the "Display items" list, find "XML Doc Comment - Tag" and select
  it. This is the style for the summary tag within XML comments.

You can now change the font color for this item by modifying the "Item foreground" color. Click on the color box next to it and select a new color.

Click "OK" to save your changes.

Please note that the exact steps and options available may vary depending on your specific version of Visual Studio 2022 or any extensions you have installed. If you cannot find the "XML Doc Comment - Tag" item or encounter any issues, consult the documentation or online resources for your specific version of Visual Studio 2022 for additional guidance.